# Manual emerge package zlib

Tags: linux, gentoo, emerge

How can I install/emerge a package manual in gentoo?

I cannot download this package ([ZLIB](http://zlib.net/zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz)), because it gets blocked by our IT-Firewall (invalid decompression table). They scan each http/ftp request and cannot open the archive properly (maybe wrong/incompatible decompression software). However, I need to install this package - IT is informed but I want a fast alternative...

I have download it manual from home but how can I emerge this package manual when I have already downloaded it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the downloaded file to `/usr/portage/distfiles/` directory, then execute `emerge` command as usual.  Make sure you have downloaded the exact version which you are going to install.